# Grouping values together based on equivalence

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix-indexing

I have a Nx2 matrix (in this case 6X2) that is as follows:

```
5  4
8  6
9  8 
10 9
15 14
16 15
```

I would like to group them in the following manner:

*(5,4) is the 1st group. It is checked with the remaining rows. Since neither 5 or 4 does not appear in the remaining rows, it may be kept as it is.

*(8,6) is the next group. However in the 3rd row 8 appears again as (9,8). So it is connected to the 2nd group ie 2nd group becomes (8,6,9,8).

*Next (10,9) is seen.But 9 belongs to the 2nd group and 10 is also added. So 2nd group is now (8,6,9,8,10,9).

*Next (15,14) is seen. It has not appeared or repeated so far. So it becomes the 3rd group ie (15,14).

*Finally, (16,15) is seen. But since 15 has repeated in the 3rd group, the group is now updated as (15,14,16,15).

In the end, `unique` command in MATLAB may be used to remove redundant elements in the groups.

I would like the final output as No of groups:

```
5   4
8   6   9   10
15  14  16
```

Note: The order of the elements in the row-wise group is not important as (5,4) or (4,5) is the same. Also I guess, the final output maybe appended with zeros so as to make it a matrix of equal dimensions i.e

```
5   4   0   0 
8   6   9  10 
15 14  16   0
```

Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code to show what you did and where exactly you have problems. You might also wanna have a look at [what SO is meant for](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Interesting and nice question :)

Comment: What's your data size? I'd say a for loop is a good (the best) starting point. What is the highest number which could appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I feel that there should be a way to do this using tree-based algorithm or a disjoint-set/union-find type approach.  But for a dirty first approach, which is likely not all that efficient, I coded the following:

```
A = [5 4
     8 6
     9 8     
    10 9
    15 14
    16 15
     8 8
     3 4
     3 1
     ];
B = mat2cell(A,ones(size(A,1),1),2);

iter = 1;
while(true)
    if (iter > size(B,1))
        break
    end
    y = B{iter};
    C = cat(1,false(iter,1),cellfun(@(x) any(sum(bsxfun(@eq,x,y'))),B(iter+1:end)));
    if any(C)
        B{iter} = (cat(2,B{iter}, B{C}));
        % or put you can start shortening them here, by calling unique() already:
        %B{iter} = unique(cat(2,B{iter}, B{C}));
        B(C) = [];
    else
        iter = iter+1;
    end
end

B = cellfun(@unique,B,'uni',false);
B{:}
```

It works out pretty alright. I don't know if this would work out for what you want, but it was fun to code up quickly. Thanks for the fun problem.

Comment: If the input is just a 2x2 matrix such as:

14 13;
13 14

which should have given an output of {13,14}.

However, the program gives an error as follows "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent." and indicates this part of the above code:


C = cat(1,false(iter,1),cellfun(@(x) any(sum(bsxfun(@eq,x,y'))),B(iter+1:end)));

Kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a general clusterization problem. The Cuthill-McKee algorithm is exactly what you search for, though it is often expressed in different terms. The good news is that Matlab implements it in the [`symrcm`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symrcm.html) function.

Here is a piece of code that works with your exemple. Note that it is quite powerfull and it is also able to deal with more complex datasets:

```
% --- Definition
D = [5 4 ; 8 6 ; 9 8 ; 10 9 ; 15 14 ; 16 15];
N = max(D(:));
U = unique(D(:));

% --- Tansformation to adjacency matrix
A = sparse(N,N);

% Diagonal element
for i = 1:numel(U)
    A(U(i),U(i)) = 1;
end

% Adjacency links
for i = 1:size(D,1)
    A(D(i,1),D(i,2)) = 1;
    A(D(i,2),D(i,1)) = 1;
end

% --- Cuthill Mc-Kee algorithm
r = symrcm(A);

% --- Find the clusters

% Preparation
B = (A(r,r)^N)>0;
i = 1;
C = {};

% Find clusters iteratively
while i<=N

     if ~any(B(:,i))
         i = i+1;
     else
         I = find(B(:,i));
         i = max(I)+1;
         C{end+1} = r(I);
     end

end

% --- Display
for i = 1:numel(C)
    disp(C{i})
end
```

and the output:

```
5     4
10     9     8     6    
16    15    14
```

Best,

Comment: Both answers are beautiful and I wish I was allowed to accept both answers. I understood aepound's answer. Of course, Ratbert's answer also worked perfectly for me. I would love to go through this "Cuthill-McKee algorithm" and get to know it better. You guys are awesome :)